# Transferring ETH from Coinbase to Etherdelta

Tags: etherdelta

I have an Ethereum wallet on Coinbase and want to transfer some ETH from Coinbase into my wallet on EtherDelta.  Can this be done and if so what is the procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: I have an Ether wallet with Coinbase and have recently opened an account with EtherDelta and have tried to many times to mention to transfer funds to EtherDelta using the above proceedure, my problem is to get Coinbase to accept my public key from EtherDelta, Coinbases message does not recognise it as being Ether. Looking forward to solving the problem.
PS; I'm not that computer savvy. Kindest Regards Ray

Answer (score 1):

Create or import an EtherDelta wallet and when making a withdrawal from your Coinbase account, use the Address you have in EtherDelta

Answer (score 0):

Put your account address for EtherDelta, not the private key, but the shorter account address on your clipboard. It looks like 0xE347BLAHBLAHBLAH49474. In coinbase, go to the Accounts tab. From there you should see your wallets. Click on your ETH wallet. Click the send button under ETH Wallet. Paste your EhherDelta ETH wallet key in the input that says "Enter ETH address". Set the amount of ETH you wish to transfer in the amounts input: either dollar amount or ETH amount. Click continue. You will pay a fee and the amount will be noted near the continue button. Deal with two step auth if set up, (get an sms and type in the code). Then done. You should be able to hop over to your etherdelta tab, jam on f5 and see your ETH in your etherdelta wallet. Happy trading.